How to Authorize in Spring boot
I'm getting acquainted with spring boot. I'm currently in the authorization section and I'm having a problem. I've authorized in the SecurityConfig file, but after having the jwt token, I authorize the api and it gives a status of 403. My token contains the following information:
{
"role": "ROLE_CUSTOMER",
"sub": "trinh1233@gmail.com",
"iat": 1724685317,
"exp": 1724721317
}
Here are my files, could you please take a look and see if I've made any mistakes?
Đây là Account.java:
package com.example.bloomgift.model;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Account")
public class Account {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "accountID") 
    private Integer accountID; 
    

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email ; 

    @Column(name= "phone")
    private Integer phone ; 

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address; 

    @Column(name= "fullname")
    private String fullname;

    @Column(name= "gender")
    private String gender ;
    
    @Column(name= "avatar")
    private String  avatar;

    @Column(name= "point")
    private Integer point; 
    
    @Column(name= "birthday")
    private Date birthday;

    @Column(name= "accountStatus")
    private Boolean accountStatus;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password; 


    @Column(name= "otp")
    private String otp ;

    @Column(name = "otp_generated_time")
    private LocalDateTime otp_generated_time;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleID")
    private Role roleID;

    public Account(){

    }
    public Account(Integer accountID, String email, Integer phone, String address, String fullname, String gender,
            String avatar, Integer point, Date birthday, Boolean accountStatus, String password, String otp,
            LocalDateTime otp_generated_time, Role roleID) {
        this.accountID = accountID;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.point = point;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.accountStatus = accountStatus;
        this.password = password;
        this.otp = otp;
        this.otp_generated_time = otp_generated_time;
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }



    public Integer getAccountID() {
        return accountID;
    }

    public void setAccountID(Integer accountID) {
        this.accountID = accountID;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(Integer phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public Integer getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Integer point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public Boolean getAccountStatus() {
        return accountStatus;
    }

    public void setAccountStatus(Boolean accountStatus) {
        this.accountStatus = accountStatus;
    }

    public String getOtp() {
        return otp;
    }

    public void setOtp(String otp) {
        this.otp = otp;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getOtp_generated_time() {
        return otp_generated_time;
    }

    public void setOtp_generated_time(LocalDateTime otp_generated_time) {
        this.otp_generated_time = otp_generated_time;
    }

    public Role getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setRoleID(Role roleID) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
   public void setPassword(String password) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        this.password = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    }
    
    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleID != null ? roleID.getRoleName() : null;
    }
   
}

Role.java:
package com.example.bloomgift.model;

import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Role")
public class Role {
     @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "roleID") 
    private Integer roleID; 

    @Column(name = "roleName")
    private String roleName ; 


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roleID")
    private Set<Account> accounts;

    public Role(){

    }

    public Role(Integer roleID, String roleName, Set<Account> accounts) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }

    public Integer getRoleID() {
        return roleID;
    }

    public void setRoleID(Integer roleID) {
        this.roleID = roleID;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public Set<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }

    public void setAccounts(Set<Account> accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }

    
}

Now I have 2 exactly roleName: 1. ROLE_ADMIN,  2. ROLE_CUSTOMER
JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:
package com.example.bloomgift.filter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.example.bloomgift.service.AccountService;
import com.example.bloomgift.utils.JwtUtil;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.accountService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                Claims claims = jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(jwt);
                String role = claims.get("role", String.class);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role)));
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

JwtUtil.java:

package com.example.bloomgift.utils;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

@Service
public class JwtUtil {
    private String SECRET_KEY = "cacfewfewfewfew";

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails, String role) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put("role", role); // Add role to claims
        return generateToken(claims, userDetails);
    }

    public String generateToken(
            Map<String, Object> extractClaim,
            UserDetails userDetails) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setClaims(extractClaim)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername().trim())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY)), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public String extractRole(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, claims -> claims.get("role", String.class)); // Extract role from claims
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

    public Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    public Boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        String username = extractUsername(token);
        return username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }

    public Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }
}

AccountService.java:
package com.example.bloomgift.service;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.example.bloomgift.model.Account;
import com.example.bloomgift.reponse.AccountReponse;
import com.example.bloomgift.repository.AccountRepository;
import com.example.bloomgift.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.bloomgift.request.AccountRequest;
import com.example.bloomgift.utils.EmailUtil;
import com.example.bloomgift.utils.OtpUtil;


@Service
public class AccountService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired 
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    
    @Autowired
    private EmailUtil emailUtil;

    @Autowired
    private OtpUtil otpUtil;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByEmail(email);

        if (account == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Email không tồn tại.");
        }

        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(account.getRoleID().getRoleName());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                account.getEmail(),
                account.getPassword(),
                Collections.singletonList(authority));
    }

SecurityConfig.java:
package com.example.bloomgift.config;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import com.example.bloomgift.filter.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import com.example.bloomgift.service.AccountService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private final AccountService accountService;
    @Autowired
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AccountService accountService, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    private static final String[] SWAGGER_URLS = {
            "/v2/api-docs",
            "/v3/api-docs",
            "/v3/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/api-docs/**",
    };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                        .requestMatchers(SWAGGER_URLS).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                // .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                //         .loginPage("http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google")
                //         .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signInWithGoogle", true))
                // .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

I really appreciate you taking the time to look through and give me answer.

This is quite not clear enough. Can you try add logger in you JwtUtils class? This may help a lot in finding the problem
